# Trouble with $arrayList.Remove($item)

Tags: powershell

I am having trouble with this.

What i am trying to do is I have 2 different array, and I am trying to exclude `$items` in `$ignore` from `$users`

I can't use where `$users | where {$ignore -notcontains $_}` because the string in the `$ignore` array may contain wildcard (e.g., admin*)

But here is the main problem, when I matched the `$item` that i want to remove, it removes my entire array instead of the selected value.

```
  [System.Collections.ArrayList]$users = Get-ADUser -Filter * | Select Name
  $users = $users.name
  $ignore = $audArr[5] -Split(",")
        
  foreach ($item in $ignore) {
      if ($item.Contains("*")) {
          foreach ($user in $users) {
               $matchResult = $user -like $item
                if ($matchResult -eq $true){
                   $users = $users.Remove($item)
               }
           }
       }
       else {
           $users = $users.Remove($item)
        }
   }
```

However, I if i try to .Add it works despite showing error

```
Cannot convert the "3" value of type "System.Int32" to type "System.Collections.ArrayList".
At C:\users\administrator\desktop\scannerTest.ps1:326 char:17
+                 $users = $users.Add($item)
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConvertToFinalInvalidCastException
```

Also, since i am already asking about powershell items.. Does anyone know what how to get LogonTime, KickoffTime via powershell? Adn what is ACB?

Comment: `.Remove(..)` is not actually _removing your entire array_, you're using it wrong, the `.Remove(..)` method doesn't produce any output hence when you do `$users = $users.Remove($item)` you're actually setting `$users` to null.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon so what are methods or ways I can use to remove a particular item? I was following here, https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-add-remove-values-in-the-array-in-powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Santiago Squarzon's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68640675/11025476) uses a good approach with regex matching. We can further enhance the regex matching to include a combination of wildcard and exact matches.

```
$users = 'John Doe','Wolverine','Mr. Pants','Administrator','Jane Doe','Master Administrator'
# two exact matches and one wildcard match
$ignore = 'john doe','jane doe','admin*'
$regex = '^({0})$' -f (($ignore -replace '\*','.*') -join '|')
# List users who don't match $ignore
$users -notmatch $regex # Jane Doe, John Doe, Administrator not listed
```

---

If you must use an ArrayList, you can apply the same technique as above by
removing successful matches:

```
[collections.ArrayList]$users = 'John Doe','Wolverine','Mr. Pants','Administrator','Jane Doe','Master Administrator'
# two exact matches and one wildcard match
$ignore = 'john doe','jane doe','admin*'
$regex = '^({0})$' -f (($ignore -replace '\*','.*') -join '|')
$users -match $regex | Foreach-Object {
    [void]$users.Remove($_)
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

In regex, alternations (basic OR logic) are separated by `|`. `.*` greedily matches any number of characters in a string. `^` denotes the beginning of a string. `$` denotes the end of a string. Putting that all together, your exact matches would look like `^exact$` and your partial matches would look like `^admin.*$` (for `admin*`) or `^.*admin.*$` (for `*admin*`). Using alternation, you can combine those matches for an `OR` effect with `^(admin.*|Benjamin Dover|Johnny Lawrence)$`.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do could be simplified to something like this:

- Create a test case, the array will have `User00` to `User10` plus `Administrators` and `Domain Admins`.

```
$ignore = @(
    'Administrators'
    'Domain Admins'
    'User05'
    'User10'
)

[System.Collections.ArrayList]$users = 0..10 |
ForEach-Object { [pscustomobject]@{Name="User{0:00}" -f $_} }
$users.Add([pscustomobject]@{Name="Administrators"})
$users.Add([pscustomobject]@{Name="Domain Admins"})
```

- Now you can simply use the `.Where(..)` method filtering those elements of the `$users` array that do *not match* the `$ignore` array on one side and those that *do match* on the other side.

```
$toIgnore = $ignore -join '|'

$notIgnoredUsers, $ignoredUsers = $users.Where({$_.Name -notmatch $toIgnore},'Split')
```

- `$notIgnoredUsers`

```
Name  
----  
User00
User01
User02
User03
User04
User06
User07
User08
User09
```

- `$ignoredUsers`

```
Name          
----          
User05        
User10        
Administrators
Domain Admins
```

---

As for how you're using the `.Remove(..)` method, since it doesn't produce any output, by doing `$users = $users.Remove($item)` you're actually setting the variable to null:

```
PS /> [System.Collections.ArrayList]$arr = 'one','two','three'

PS /> $arr = $arr.Remove('one')

PS /> $null -eq $arr
True
```

If you want to remove `one` from the list you would simply do `$arr.Remove('one')`.